# How to check if $\text{position}\left(\frac{a + b} 2\right )$ is in range $\text{position}\left(a\right )$ and $\text{position}\left(b\right )$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, permutations

Given a permutation of $n$ number $1, 2, 3,\dots,n$. How to check if it is exist $a,\ b$ with the same parity such that $\frac {a + b} 2$ is between $a, b$.

How to solve this problem efficiently ? (approximate algorithm is good too)

Comment: Apparently, not always. For example, $(1,5,3,2,4)$ and $(1,7,3,5,2,6,4)$. Segregating even and odd numbers seems to work well on creating such examples.

Comment: @IanMateus, your second example fails due to $a=1, b=5$.

Comment: @vadim123 Indeed, sorry. We can use $(1,5,7,3,2,6,4)$ instead.

Comment: I want to ask for a given specific permutation, how to check the answer efficiently ?

Comment: I think this can happen for any length. Indeed, by induction: Check out a bad sequence such as $(1,5,3,2,4)$. Multiplying everyone by two gives $(2,10,6,4,8)$, a bad permutation of even numbers. Now, lower everyone in the new sequence by one: we get $(1,9,5,3,7)$, a bad sequence of odd numbers. Now get everyone together, since they don't mix: $(1,9,5,3,7,2,10,6,4,8)$. This construction took a bad of length $5$ and constructed one of length $2\cdot 5$. Since removing members of a bad sequence keeps it bad, bad sequences of arbitrary length exist.

Comment: @Ian, i think you misunderstood my question (sorry for my english),  the problem ask for *a given* permutation,  not all permutation of length n.

Comment: For example input 1 2 3,  output yes.  Input 1 3 2,  output no

Comment: @Xeing I understood the question, these are only some observations :-)

Comment: I don't think you're going to find an algorithm better than $O(n^2)$.  For each pair $(a,b)$ of the same parity, there is a binary question that needs to be checked.  Knowledge of the answer does not tell you the answer for any other pair.

Comment: Simiar to this problem I guess , http://codeforces.com/contest/452/problem/F . (Note : This is from an already completed contest)

Answer (score 1):

My first idea: Let's say you have numbers $x,y,z$ in your permutation with $y=\frac{x+z}{2}$ and they appear in that order. This means $y-x=z-y$ must hold true. Now iterate through all possible values of $y$, i. e. all numbers at position $2,\dots,n-1$ and generate two lists: calculate $y-x$ for all values $x$ left of $y$, and $z-y$ for all values $z$ to the right of $y$. If you find a matching number in these lists, answer is yes, otherwise no.

Example: Permutation is $(5,1,6,4,2,7,3)$. First step $y=1$ yields the lists: $(-4)$ and $(5,3,1,6,2)$ with no matches. In the second step $y=6$ we get $(\mathbf{1},5)$ and $(-2,-4,\mathbf{1},-3)$. The matching number 1 corresponds to 5, 6 and 7 in the permutation. This should have cubic time complexity. If that's not fast enough for you, I would consider using some sort of tree based algorithm.

Update: I implemented this algorithm and made some tests. For a random permutation the algorithm is quite fast and can compute the answer up to $n=100000$ in a matter of seconds. But of course, the bigger your $n$, the harder it gets to find a permutation which *doesn't* have the desired property: For example for $n=9$ we already have 99.9 % permutations which stand the test. So most of the times you only have to compute some of the lists in order to get the result. But if you had to check *all of the permutations for a given n* you're gonna need some other methods...